# Is there a grammatical mistake in the phrase "name someone's name"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

For example, can the host of a TV show, like "Weakest link", ask a contestant such a question:

> Name the name of the 45th US president.

I think it may be some kind of tautology. I am really not good at word usage, but I suggest it would be better to say either:

> 1) Tell the name of the 45th US president.

or

> 2) Say the name of the 45th US president.

or

> 3) Name the 45th US president.

(without the noun "name").

So is there a mistake in my initial question, and if it is, which substitution would be the best?

Comment: More idiomatic: *What is the name of the 45th US president?*

Comment: @Davo, thanks. I thought of using a wh-question instead of imperative. I agree it sounds better.

Comment: But what about the phrase "name a name..."? For example, "Name a name of a famous robber." That means that any robber's name will work: Butch Cassidy, John Dillinger, Ned Kelly et cetera. I think in that case one cannot ask: "What is a name of a famous robber?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite its apparent awkwardness, I prefer the original (i.e., *Name the name*) over either of your suggestions (*Say the name*, or *Tell the name*).

The verb *name* is often used in a quiz show format; for example:

> Name the general who was defeated at Waterloo.
>   Name the Canadian province which comes last alphabetically.
>   Name the sport invented by William G. Morgan in Holyoke, Massachusetts.

The verbs *say* and *tell* merely mean “recite” or “say aloud”. The verb *name* adds to that a notion of correctness. NOAD says:

> **name** (*v.*) give the correct name for

---

As for your third option:

> Name the 45th US president

I find that more acceptable; however, I wouldn’t go so far as to say the original has a “mistake” or that such a change is necessary.